# Flutter - how to convert .txt to json?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm receiving a `.txt` file (from remote) and it's formatted to look like a json file, however it's impossible to get this in same way (to fetch data). So here's my question. Is there a way to convert this `.txt` file (response) to json?

That's how it's looks like:

```json
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "number": "1000",
      "text": "Regular boring name"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "number": "43",
      "text": "Cool name"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "number": "28",
      "text": "Some other name"
    },
  ]
}
```

I've already read this by using

```dart
Future<String> fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get(baseUrl);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var decoded = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
      print(decoded);
      return decoded;
    } else {
      return "Error";
    }
  }
```

but now I have to convert it somehow to json and I have no idea how to do it

Comment: `final data = json.decode(response.body)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [website](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) to convert you'r json response to dart class first. for this response you can get this result from website:

```
class resultClass {
  String id;
  String number;
  String text;

  resultClass({this.id, this.number, this.text});

  resultClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    number = json['number'];
    text = json['text'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['number'] = this.number;
    data['text'] = this.text;
    return data;
  }
}
```

and then changne you't code to this:

```
Future<Category> fetchData() async {
    result;
    final response = await http.get(baseUrl);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        result = (response.data as List)
        .map((item) => resultClass.fromJson(item))
        .toList()
        return result;
    } 
    return result;
}
```

I hope this help to you.

Comment: Thanks, I had my Model and Entities prepared previously I was just missing a part which @pskink wrote and now everything is fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just take the string and use jsonDecode

```
Map x = jsonDecode(theSringWhichIsFormattedLikeAMap);
```